# Continuity of contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, denote $S=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0 \leq \text{Re}(z) \leq 1\}$ and let $f:S \rightarrow X$ be a continuous function satisfying that $\|f\|_{\infty}= \sup_{z \in S}\|f(z)\|_X<+ \infty (*)$. Define a function $g:S \rightarrow X$ by the formula $g(z) = \int_{[0,z]}f(\zeta)d\zeta$. I want to prove that **$\boldsymbol{g}$ is continuous**.

*My attempt:*

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $S$ that converges to some $z \in S$. We aim to show that $g(z_n) \rightarrow g(z)$ in $X$. We have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|g(z_n)-g(z)\|_X &= \| \int_{[0,z_n]}f(\zeta)d\zeta-\int_{[0,z]}f(\zeta) d\zeta\|_X\\
&=\| \int_{t=0}^{1}f(tz_n) z_n dt- \int_{t=0}^{1}f(tz)zdt\|_X\\
&\leq \|\int_{t=0}^{1} f(tz_n)z_ndt-\int_{t=0}^1f(tz)z_ndt\|_X\\
&+\|\int_{t=0}^{1} f(tz)z_ndt-\int_{t=0}^1f(tz)zdt\|_X\\
&\leq |z_n| \cdot \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \|f(tz_n)-f(tz)\|_X+|z_n-z| \cdot \sup_{t \in [0,1]}\|f(tz\|_X.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now, by $z_n \rightarrow z$ and $(*)$, the second summand goes to $0$. However, I don't know how to prove that $\boldsymbol{\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \|f(tz_n)-f(tz)\|_X \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0}$. I see that since $z_n \rightarrow z$ the continuity of $f$ gives that $f(tz_n) \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|_X} f(tz)$ but I am not sure how to control the $\sup_{t\in [0,1]}$.

*Comments:*

1. I don't think that the arbitrariness of the Banach space $X$ plays any special role here so you may as well consider $X=\mathbb{C}$.
2. I also have that $f$ is holomorphic in the interior of $S$, but I don't think that's needed here.

Comment: Fix a point $z$, and restrict your attention to a small compact set $K\subset S$ around $z$ with non-empty interior (eg. a disk or a half disc if $z$ is a boundary point of $S$) , and consider $F:K\times [0,1]\to X$ defined as $F(w,t)=f(tw)\cdot w$. This is a continuous function on a compact set, hence uniformly continuous. So if $w_1,w_2\in K$ are close enough, what can you say about $\|F(w_1,t)-F(w_2,t)\|_X$?

Comment: In particular, the assumption $\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty$ is unnecessary.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I  understand the idea, although I have some trouble with the exact formulation. Can you write down your argument in detail?

Comment: Write out the definition of uniform continuity for $F$

Comment: @peek-a-boo If I did my computations right you showed that $\sup_{t \in [0,1]}\|f(tz_n)z_n-f(tz)z\|_X \rightarrow 0$ so that the quantity $\int_{t=0}^{1} f(tz) z_n dt$ I added and subtracted was unnecessary (which is of course fine), right?

Comment: Right, because of uniform continuity there was no need to add and subtract